# jquery.mobile: orientation causes width error

Tags: asp.net, ipad, jquery-mobile, mobile, windows-phone-8

I have some pages based upon jquery.mobile; when I rotate the device (WP8/IE10 & iPad2) the page re-renders with the incorrect width.

On the iPad2, the same occurs if I activate the keyboard by clicking in a textbox and then clicking out of it again.

My page code (as rendered):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="author" content="Martin Robins" />
  <title>Do stuff</title>
  <link href="../Content/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="../Content/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="../Content/jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="./" id="form">
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
        $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
        $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
      });
    </script>

    <div data-role="page" id="logon" data-theme="c">
      <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        <h1>Select location</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content">

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <legend>Title</legend>
            <input name="ctl00$FormContentPlaceHolder$Prefix" type="text" id="FormContentPlaceHolder_Prefix" style="text-transform: capitalize;" />
          </fieldset>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <legend>Forenames</legend>
            <input name="ctl00$FormContentPlaceHolder$Forenames" type="text" vcard_name="vCard.FirstName" id="FormContentPlaceHolder_Forenames" style="text-transform: capitalize;" />
          </fieldset>
        </div>                  
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: some content has been left out. I am using ASP.NET so there are some ASP.NET AJAX scripts also being loaded.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be I think this is a meta tag issue, could you please add the following meta tag and check if this works.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Comment: Apologies for the delay in responding to your suggestion, it has taken me a while to get my hands on an iPad again for testing. This did not however resolve the problem. If I click in a textbox and then click on the background (thus dropping the keyboard) the width changes to about 75%.

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> was the answer; I am marking you correct though as you provided enough of the answer for me to find the rest.